# Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF83EBEA1E (ucrtbase.dll) in python.exe: Fatal program exit requested. occurred

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-10

When I click on python.exe I get this error (it used to run, so I am not sure which of my previous activities has damaged it):
[image]

This is the result of debugging it:
[image]

Here's what the exception says specifically:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF83EBEA1E (ucrtbase.dll) in python.exe: Fatal program exit requested. occurred
```

And the error itself is:

```
Fatal Python Error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
```

Here's the path in env variables:
[image]

Comment: By any chance did you notice that path in the error, `C:\Python27\Lib\encodings`? It seems you have `PYTHONHOME` set to `C:\Python27`, which will break every other installation of Python. That environment variable should rarely be used, and never set permanently.

Comment: Somehow you're running python3 against the python2 stdlib.

Comment: @eryksun please see the last photo uploaded regarding env path and suggest what I can do?

Comment: OK, it's not `PYTHONHOME`. It's an incorrect `PYTHONPATH`. Delete every item except for `C:\Workspace\universe`.